# startForeground without the notification alert

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

startForeground naturally uses a notification. However, I would like not to play the alert sound/vibration. Is it possible to achieve that ?

Comment: Change the importance of the notification channel you create.

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thank you :)